# how is this add method supposed to add 2 numbers if it only accepts 1 parameter?

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment where I need to do calculations with large numbers without using bignumber class.

I understand the theory now on how I will be adding the 2 numbers ( i have them taken in as strings, then inserted into int arrays) I will add the last digits and take anything over 9 and add it to the next.

I have been supplied with this method to use though:

```
LargeInteger sum = firstInt.add(secondInt);
```

I'm a bit confused as to how I can make this method in that it only takes 1 of the 2 numbers in the parameters.

Here is the rest of the pertinant code I have done so far:

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string1;
    String string2;
    int exp =0;

    System.out.print("Enter the first integer: ");
    //Store up the input string “string1” entered by the user from the keyboard.
    string1 = input.next(); 

    LargeInteger firstInt = new LargeInteger(string1);

    System.out.print("Enter the second integer: ");
    string2 = input.next(); 
    //Store up the input string “string2” entered by the user from the keyboard.
    LargeInteger secondInt = new LargeInteger(string2);

    LargeInteger sum = firstInt.add(secondInt);

    System.out.printf (" Sum = %s \n", sum.display());

}
```

And here is my second class LargeInteger (without the add method yet):

```
public class LargeInteger {
    private int[] intArray;

    //convert the strings to array
    public LargeInteger(String s) { 
        intArray = new int[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10); // in base 10
        }
    }

    //display the strings
    public String display() {           
        String result="";

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
            result += intArray[i];
        }
        return result.toString();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do have two values. The first one is in firstInt and the second is in secondInt. The first value is implicitly available to the method add.

You will, however, need a method to get the value of intArray from the other object.

```
public int[] getIntArray() {
   return intArray;
}
```

So within your add method, the values of secondInt.intArray are accessible by calling

```
int[] otherValues = secondInt.getIntArray();
```

Comment: How do I use the firstInt then from within the method add? I think that is what I don't understand

Comment: For doing the steps that you described, you need access to the intArray property in both objects. Now, for firstInt, you can get that value just by using intArray. As it is within the object itself, you can directly access it. For secondInt, however, you will need to define a method which will get you the value of intArray. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: ok it's starting to make a bit of sense, When I tried this though eclipse tells me that secondInt can't be resolved in the add method. so am I supposed to create a local variable secondInt?

Comment: Well, when you're defining the method add, you pass the secondInt as a parameter. This way it'll be accessible to your method

Comment: right rightt.. I think i need to regroup a bit.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

```
LargeInteger sum = firstInt.add(secondInt);
```

This mean :
Please `firstInt`, can you give the result of adding `secondInt` to yourself?

Answer (score 1):

well you're calling the function ON a number which you wish to add...so you're only getting one parameter, but since the add function is part of your LargeInteger class, you only need one number.

**ex:**

```
   public class LargeInteger{

    public int add(String secondNumber){

    int secondNum = Integer.ParseInt(secondNumber);
    return this + secondNum;

    }
```

Comment: I think what I dont understand is how to create the add method, and call on the first number from within that method?

Comment: Thank you for the example but.. I still don't understand how this works. This method has nothing to do with the firstInt. firstInt.add(secondInt); I can see that it is being called right there from firstInt.. So I get that there is a relationship here but.. I don't understand how it will know to add that digit? I feel slow :(

Comment: This may not work if the string passed as input to LargeInteger is greater than what Integer can hold.

Comment: LargeInteger firstInt = new LargeInteger("5");
firstInt.add("5");

in the add function you get
this + second int, and 'this' is the object which has the method, so  firstInt

Answer (score 1):

Use algorithm to add 2 integer numbers. I will try to wrote you an example, supose we have 2 integer arrays

```
int maxIterations = Math.min(array1.size, array2.size);
int currentResult; //to store result should be writen
int[] resultArray = new Integer[Math.max(array1.size, array2.size) + 1];
int needToAdd = 0; //to store result should be added next step
for(int i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
    currentResult = array1[i] + array2[i];
    resultArray[i] = currentResult % 10 + needToAdd; //if more than 9 its correct answer
    needToAdd = currentResult / 10; //this is what you need to add on next step
}
resultArray[Math.max(array1.size, array2.size) + 1] = needToAdd;
return resultArray.reverse();
```

We should check for leading zero when we store information and thats all :) This will work for very very big numbers :)
Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In this context - `LargeInteger` is what is described as *immutable*, i.e. it never modifies it self, instead what that function will do is construct a new `LargeInteger` with it's value and the value that you've passed in. Hence the addition...